# What is the maximum length i can choose for a USB cable made up of CAT6 shielded cable?

Tags: usb

After frequent research over internet I found that USB can be extended beyond standard USB length limit of 5 meters. 
There are few methods such as USB hubs and USB Active repeater cables that allow us to extend length up to 30 meters. But i wanted even more than 30 meter without loosing much signal. 
I basically want to connect a data card/dongle to such cable.
Currently I use high quality(may not be?) USB extension cable of 5 meter , but even with this cable i have problem of auto disconnection device frequently, so I'm afraid of trying out any other options.

Recently I came through this video where the author says USB can be extended more than 100ft: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YaNfmhrJ7g8

The idea is to use pair of two USB to ethernet converter and vice versa, and use CAT6 cable of desired length in between.

For connecting a data card (Huawei E3131) using above method and a sheilded cat6 cable, how much length i can achieve without experiencing problems of disconnecting fequently?

Comment: Repeat of [Maximum length of a USB cable](http://superuser.com/questions/64744/maximum-length-of-a-usb-cable) on SuperUser. Please don't expect us to watch the video. By all means link to it but type out a summary of the theory that the video promotes.

Comment: It depends on the specific model of converter you buy. This is essentially a shopping question, and off-topic here.

Comment: Those length limitations in bus systems often are caused by the transmission error detection methods and the time they require for transmitting an error signal. However, having that conversion to another bus system and back in between your two devices would definitely increase your latency which could cause problems.

Comment: @transistor If you don't have patience to read, then why do you waste you time by searching for similar questions and typing in comments ? I've explained the theory of video in one line so as to become it easy to read. Also it is not at all exact copy of given link, as it is special case in which we are trying to increase length beyond standards. I have  not forced anyone to watch the video, just added it for interested people. Don't act over smart because you got high reputation. Anyway i've got right answer from another user better than you.

Comment: @DaveTweed How can it become a shopping question ? Did i ask which product has more discount ? or which product is best out of given list ? I just requested for possible outcome when cables of different types combined together. I've also specified "MAXIMUM", because I know it depends on converters used.

Comment: This is a shopping question. OP needs to solve own problem with the cable the OP bought or might buy. Vote to close.

Comment: No, this is a fundamental question about how USB works. See my answer in old SperUser thread [link](http://superuser.com/questions/64744/maximum-length-of-a-usb-cable/1105099#1105099)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the OEM of the hardware has conformed to the [10/100/1000BASE-T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_over_twisted_pair) standards, then it appears that the [CAT6 defined operating length limit is 100 meters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_6_cable#Maximum_length).  Note there are exceptions as listed in the link.